# Tension Problem (Classical Mechanics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

An exercise from my textbook revealed to me that I have some misconceptions about Newtonian mechanics. The textbook gives the answers to the questions, but I'm hoping someone can explain how it works and how I've misunderstood it.

The problem in question is exercise 105 from [OpenStax University Physics Volume 1: Chapter 5 Review - Challenge Problems](https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/5-challenge-problems).

> Hanging from the ceiling over a baby bed, well out of baby’s reach, is a string with plastic shapes, as shown here. The string is taut (there is no slack), as shown by the straight segments. Each plastic shape has the same mass $m$, and they are equally spaced by a distance $d$, as shown. The angles labeled $$ describe the angle formed by the end of the string and the ceiling at each end. The center length of sting is horizontal. The remaining two segments each form an angle with the horizontal, labeled . Let $T_1$ be the tension in the leftmost section of the string, $_2$ be the tension in the section adjacent to it, and $_3$ be the tension in the horizontal segment. (a) Find an equation for the tension in each section of the string in terms of the variables $m$, $g$, and $$. (b) Find the angle  in terms of the angle . (c) If $=5.10°$, what is the value of ? (d) Find the distance $x$ between the endpoints in terms of $d$ and .
> [image]

Here's my thinking on the subject:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
2\vec{T_1} \sin{\theta } + 2\vec{T_2} \sin{\phi } & = -\sum{\vec{F_{gravity}}} \\
    \vec{T_1} \sin{\theta } & = -\vec{F_{g_{cow}}} = -(-m_{cow}g) = m_{cow}g \\
\vec{T_1} & = \frac{m_{cow}g}{\sin{\theta }} = \frac{mg}{\sin{\theta }}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Why is this wrong? By what process could I have come up with the right answer? Having failed to answer a.), I didn't attempt the other parts of the question.

[SPOILER ALERT]

The correct answers are:

> a.) $T_1 = \frac{2mg}{sin{\theta }}$, $T_2 = \frac{mg}{\sin(\arctan(\frac{1}{2}\tan{\theta}))} $, $T_3 = \frac{2mg}{\tan{\theta }}$ 
> b.) $\phi = \arctan(\frac{1}{2}\tan{\theta })$ 
> c.) $2.56^{\circ }$ 
> d.) $x = d (2\cos{\theta } + 2\cos (\arctan (\frac{1}{2} \tan{\theta })) + 1)$

Where'd the **2** come from in $T_1 = \frac{2mg}{sin{\theta }}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I figured out what I did wrong, and how to do it right. What was wrong with my original thinking, at least in part, was I didn't consider the y component of the tension between the cow and the chicken in the diagram.

So here's how to do it right. First, consider each of the points of intersection between strings (where the angle changes) and draw a free body diagram showing the forces acting upon that point.

[image: free body diagram]

From these I could deduce:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
T_3 & = T_2 \cos{\phi } \\
T_2 \sin{\phi } & = mg \\
T_1 \sin{\theta } & = T_2 \sin{\phi } + mg
\end{split}
\end{equation}

With a little algebra

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
T_2 & = \frac{mg}{\sin{\phi}} \\
T_1 \sin{\theta} & = \frac{mg\sin{\phi}}{\sin{\phi}} + mg \\
T_1 \sin{\theta} & = 2mg \\
T_1 = \frac{2mg}{\sin{\theta}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I was able to derive the other answers in a similar manner.